# Incluir o valor de uma variável dentro de uma outra string

Tags: excel-vba

Gostaria de saber se é possível colocar o valor de uma variável tipo string dentro de uma outra string.

Exemplo:

```
Dim name As String
Set name  = "Bruno"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _"\Colegio\compartilhamentos\secretaria\aluno - name.xlsx
```

Dessa forma o nome do arquivo ficaria assim: \Colegio\compartilhamentos\secretaria\aluno - Bruno.xlsx

Comment: Talvez a instrução ```Set``` dê erro, Osvaldo. ```Set``` é a instrução para atribuir OBJETOS a uma variável. Para atribuir valores que não sejam objetos, a instrução correta é a ```Let``` (que ninguém usa, porque é a instrução padrão implícita). Portanto, sua segunda linha deveria ser apenas ```name = "Bruno"```

Comment: Obrigado, César! Desconhecia essa informação.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o **concatenador &**. Faça o seguinte:

```
Dim name As String
Set name  = "Bruno"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _"\Colegio\compartilhamentos\secretaria\aluno - " & name & ".xlsx"
```